# How to draw bounding boxes on the detected contours in Scikit-Image?

Tags: bounding-box, scikit-image

I tried to find a way to draw a bounding box on the contours detected in scikit-image, but I didn't find any way as the find_contours in scikit-image method returns a 2-dimensional array of the co-ordinate points of the detected contours.

Comment: You can get the min- and max-coordnates ( x,y ) in your detected contour array. Now generate a bounding box for it.

Comment: @KimKulling So, you are suggesting to draw a  bounding box by taking the (x, y) as the starting point and adding random values to the starting point to make it as an endpoint. 

But is there a way to find the area of the contour in scikit-image?

Comment: The gallery contains an example of how to draw detected contours: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_contours.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-edges-plot-contours-py  We're also implementing a box drawing function as we speak.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt Good to hear from you. But, is there a way to extract the area of each of the detected contours? So, we can only consider the largest contour in terms of the area.

Comment: Given that you have the contour coordinates, you can use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt Thanks Stefan. Will try this out.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this piece of code to draw bounds on your image:

```py
# Loop through contours and draw the bounds in red
contours = skimage.measure.find_contours(img, level)

for contour in contours:
    img = drawShape(img, contour, [255, 0, 0]) 

def drawShape(img, coordinates, color):
    # In order to draw our line in red
    img = skimage.color.gray2rgb(img)

    # Make sure the coordinates are expressed as integers
    coordinates = coordinates.astype(int)

    img[coordinates[:, 0], coordinates[:, 1]] = color

    return img
```